# How do we read all the cookies in the background in CrossRider?

Tags: browser-extension, crossrider

We are using CrossRider to develop an extension for Internet Explorer. We are using `appAPI.request.get` in the background. However, I noticed that the server received the request without cookies.

Are cookies sent to the server when using `appAPI.request.get`? (if there are cookies to the required domain). And if not, how do we read all the cookies for a specific domain?

We need to read the cookies and that's why I used `appAPI.request.get` (we have a Python program which returns the cookies in JSON).

Comment: By the way, I checked again now and it seems that `appAPI.request.get` does use cookies, but they are different than Internet Explorer's regular cookies for the specific domain. Is it possible that the background in CrossRider has different cookies? I saw the same bug in Safari 5 (without CrossRider), but it doesn't exist in Safari 7.

Comment: Off the top of my head, in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari cookies are sent with appAPI.request in the background scope but in Internet Explorer they are not and it's not possible due to a scoping issue. [**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I understand that `appAPI.request.get` doesn't send cookies in the background in Internet Explorer. The solution I found is this: the background will send a message to the active tab, the active tab will use `appAPI.request.get` to send a message to the server (with the cookies of the specific domain), and will return the cookies to the background. Here is the code:

Background:

```
// get_cookies_url is the url of the script on the server.

var mCallbackMap;
var message = {message_id: Math.floor((Math.random() * 900000000000000) + 100000000000000)};
if (typeof mCallbackMap === 'undefined') {
    mCallbackMap = {};
    appAPI.message.addListener({channel: "read_all_cookies_response"}, function(message) {
        if (typeof mCallbackMap[message.message_id] === 'function') {
            mCallbackMap[message.message_id](message.cookies);
            delete mCallbackMap[message.message_id];
        }
    });
}

(function(callback_inner) {
    mCallbackMap[message.message_id] = function(cookies) {
        if (typeof(callback_inner) === 'function') {
            callback_inner(cookies);
        }
    };
})(callback);

appAPI.message.toActiveTab({'url': get_cookies_url, 'message_id': message.message_id}, {channel: "read_all_cookies"});
```

extension.js:

```
appAPI.message.addListener({channel: "read_all_cookies"}, function(message) {
    appAPI.request.get({
        url: message.url,
        onSuccess: function(response, additionalInfo) {
            var cookies = JSON.parse(response);
            appAPI.message.toBackground({cookies: cookies, message_id: message.message_id}, {channel: "read_all_cookies_response"});
        }
    });
});
```

(`mCallbackMap` is defined only once and can be related to the controller object, such as `Controller.mCallbackMap`).